# Using libhttpserver to build https server

Tags: c++, ssl, https, httpserver

I am trying to compile the below piece of code to run a basic https server and i am encountering an error which i am not able to resolve. The class hello_world_resource is responsible for the server startup and the return statement gives the response that the server should give when it is accessed.

the url for the server is defined by function 'register_resource'

the url for the github documentation of the library - https://github.com/etr/libhttpserver

I've tried downloading ssl and curl multiple times and searched the google too but i am still not able to find the cause for this problem.

abcd.key and xyz.crt are the self-signed certificates that i generated following this procedure online - 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04

```
#include <httpserver.hpp>
using namespace httpserver;

class hello_world_resource : public http_resource 
{
    public:
    const std::shared_ptr<http_response> render(const http_request&) 
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<http_response>(new 
        string_response("Hello, World!"));
    }
};

int main() 
{
     webserver ws = create_webserver(8080)
         .use_ssl()
         .https_mem_key("/path/to/abcd.key")
        .https_mem_cert("/path/to/xyz.crt");

        hello_world_resource hwr;
        ws.register_resource("/hello", &hwr);
        ws.start(true);

    return 0;
}
```

The error being thrown is :

***terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
what():  BD
             A
(G BBJ
Aborted***

the code should run and a server should be available at - https://localhost:8080/hello

Comment: Which statement is throwing the exception ? Try surrounding your code with `try catch` statement and show the exception message.

Comment: @Clonk i tried that and the ressponse i got was what i have written after "what()"

Comment: @KaranMotiramani I've just compiled your code in local and generated key and certificate using the link you posted (which is pretty standard). It works for me. Have you made sure that the user running the server has read permissions on your key file?
Openssl generates them with 'rw' permissions only for the owner and given you used 'sudo' to generate them, that will be root.